# Get location of an element(column) which is dynamically created by lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-datatable

[image: Contact lightning-datatable]

This is the lightning datatable and I want to get the location of **Email** column (3rd). But the problem is that there is no HTML code for the table, so I can not use querySelector for it. Lightning datatable dynamically creates the whole table itself.

**Here is my code :**

**main.html**

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import generateData from './generateData';

const actions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
];

const columns = [
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'First Name' },
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'Last Name' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Account Name' },
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions },
    },
];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        const data = generateData({ amountOfRecords: 5 });
        this.data = data;
    }

handleRowAction(event) {
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'delete':
                this.deleteRow(row);
                break;
            case 'show_details':
                this.showRowDetails(row);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    deleteRow(row) {
        const { id } = row;
        const index = this.findRowIndexById(id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.data = this.data
                .slice(0, index)
                .concat(this.data.slice(index + 1));
        }
    }

    findRowIndexById(id) {
        let ret = -1;
        this.data.some((row, index) => {
            if (row.id === id) {
                ret = index;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The data you want to get to is already present in the source data that feeds into `columns`. What are you trying to accomplish by querying the table cell? Explaining your underlying business problem would allow us to help you out better.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I don't want data or any other stuff I only want **location** of that column. I want to show a popup on 3rd column (Email), so that's why I want the **top**  or **left coordinates** .

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The Shadow DOM, however, prevents you from reading "closed" components, of which all standard components are closed. You'd have to implement something from scratch in order for you to get at those details. The best you can get away with would be to check the clientX/clientY properties to determine where to draw something.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use Shadow DOM to create HTML markup and then use querySelector to find desired element.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom

Comment: Thanks, for your help. But querySelector don't work for the elements of Datatable (for eg. - Datatable creates column and row elemetns after it render) and the only element we can find using querySelector is "lightning-datatable".